# Google Play Security Alert X509Trustmanager - Will my App be removed from store after May 17?

Tags: google-play, titanium, appcelerator, trustmanager

I have an App, developed in Titanium, in Google play that have the Trustmanager Security Alert. The alert says:

"Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability. Please address this issue as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning May 17, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates containing the unsafe implementation of the interface X509TrustManager."

My question is will my app be removed after May 17 if I don't update it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. But you will not be able publish app that has this issue from May 17.

Some Appcelerator apps is facing this issue recently but Appcelerator team also has fixed this in their API. So nothing to worry for Appcelerator users.

You can follow this here :[JIRA LINK](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20431)